# How to get type annotations for class members?

Tags: python, typing, inspect

Consider the following code:

```
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz: Optional[int] = None
```

How do I find in code that baz has type `Optional[int]`? If I do `type(Foo().baz)`, I only get `None`.

Comment: `type` isn't how you access typing data anyway, it's in `__annotations__`. But I don't think annotations inside a method like that will get exposed anywhere; typically you'd included it in the parameter list, i.e. `(self, baz: Optional[int] = None)`, then it would be in `Foo.__init__.__annotations__`.

Comment: `mypy` finds them just fine, at least for init. I was hoping to be able to uses these as well in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the instance attribute type in the class body, as described in the  [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)

```py
from typing import Optional, get_type_hints

class Foo:
    baz: Optional[int]

    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = None


get_type_hints(Foo)

Out[26]: {'baz': typing.Union[int, NoneType]}
```

Note that `typing.Union[int, NoneType]` is the same as `Optional[int]`.

Comment: Doesn't this also define `Foo.baz` as a valid variable to use?

Comment: Besides `Foo().baz`, I mean.

Comment: no, that would be the case if you did `baz: Optional[int] = None` in the class body. with the class in the answer `Foo.baz` gives an `AttributeError`

Comment: check out the linked PEP, which has a lot of examples

Comment: As long as I don't assign a value it works, thanks!